# Почему при передаче объекта в instance ModelForm дата передается, но не отображается?

Tags: django

Делаю формочку для редактирования объекта бд, хочу сделать так, чтобы при открытии страницы с формой в ней уже были данные. Передаю в instance нужный объект, но значения отображаются только в полх NumberField, Select и TextInput
При этом в дебагере при инициализации формы и в return значения values заполнены у всех полей.
Я открыл код элемента и увидел, что value поля заполнено, но в самом поле выводится "дд.мм.гггг".
Кто уже сталкивался с такой проблемой, подскажите что делать?
Что вообще не так?

```
if request.method == 'GET':
    form = EditDeistForm(instance=Deist.objects.get(id=objId))
    return render(request, 'editDeist.html', {
        'form': form,    # в шаблоне просто вызываю {{ form.field } по нужному порядку и все
        'objId': objId
    })
```

Comment: Сложно что-то сказать не видя кода. Было бы неплохо, если ты покажешь view  в которой рендеришь html и сам html с формой

Comment: (view)
if request.method == 'GET':
        form = EditDeistForm(instance=Deist.objects.get(id=objId))
        return render(request, 'editDeist.html', {
            'form': form,
            'objId': objId
        })

в шаблоне просто вызываю {{ form.field }} по нужному порядку и все

Comment: лучше обнови вопрос и вставь там код, что бы было читаемым